# How to set conversation message and time in same row like whatsapp?

Tags: android, whatsapp

[image]

I created whatsapp chat layout. I dont know how to set message and delivery time in same chat bubble? Which layout is better to wrapping the text when its size was big?

Comment: post your code, what is the problem you are facing and what have you tried?

Comment: `Which layout is better to wrapping the text ...?` You choose: **Every** layout has a `wrap_content` propriety which can be assigned to its width and/or height.

Answer (score -1):

There's something called as 9patch image which you can use in your chat bubble.
9Patch image will shrink or resize depending on your text length. And for the layout you can use LinearLayout with orientation horizontal.